# MySQL High CPU Consumption (600%)

Tags: mysql, performance, caching, cpu

We have a high traffic server running mysql. This database has run fine for years with no significant spikes in traffic or changes to the database but recently Mysql CPU consumption has spiked to a consistent 600%.

We don't see any slow queries being logged but we get the following recommendations.

We're not very knowledgeable with MySQL and everything we've tried to fix the CPU consumption has not worked.

If anyone can provide some recommended settings that would be appreciated.

```
top - 08:08:59 up 313 days, 12:47,  2 users,  load average: 7.21, 6.48, 6.08
Tasks: 294 total,   1 running, 293 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 29.9%us, 10.6%sy,  3.9%ni, 47.1%id,  3.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  5.5%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8018016k total,  7869300k used,   148716k free,   587632k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  5894136k cached

[mysqld]
# skip-networking
#tmpdir=/dev/shm
general_log = 1
slow_query_log = 1
log-slow-queries = /var/log/mysql-slow.log
slow-query_log_file = /var/log/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
sort_buffer_size = 4M
max_connections = 151
max_allowed_packet = 100M
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_limit = 5M
join_buffer_size = 10M
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 4
table_cache = 20k
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
key_buffer_size = 128M
local-infile=0
open_files_limit=2058
wait_timeout = 500
connect_timeout = 500
interactive_timeout = 500
performance_schema = on


 >>  MySQLTuner 1.4.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[OK] Logged in using credentials passed on the command line
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.50-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM 
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 453M (Tables: 169)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[!!] InnoDB is enabled but isn't being used
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 5

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 22m 39s (763K q [561.834 qps], 22K conn, TX: 506M, RX: 95M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 71% / 29%
[--] Total buffers: 848.0M global + 14.6M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 3.0G (39% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (1/763K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 52% (80/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/273.3M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (72M cached / 29K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 79.1% (472K cached / 596K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (8 temp sorts / 43K sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (37 on disk / 10K total)
[!!] Thread cache hit rate: 47% (12K created / 22K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 97% (249 open / 256 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (277/41K)
[!!] Table locks acquired immediately: 53%

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Add skip-innodb to MySQL configuration to disable InnoDB
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Optimize queries and/or use InnoDB to reduce lock wait
Variables to adjust:
    thread_cache_size (> 4)
```

**Suboptimal caching method.**

You are using the MySQL Query cache with a fairly high traffic database. It might be worth considering to use memcached instead of the MySQL Query cache, especially if you have multiple slaves.

**Less than 80% of the query cache is being utilized.**

This might be caused by query_cache_limit being too low. Flushing the query cache might help as well.

**The query cache is considerably fragmented.**

Severe fragmentation is likely to (further) increase Qcache_lowmem_prunes. This might be caused by many Query cache low memory prunes due to query_cache_size being too small. For a immediate but short lived fix you can flush the query cache (might lock the query cache for a long time). Carefully adjusting query_cache_min_res_unit to a lower value might help too, e.g. you can set it to the average size of your queries in the cache using this formula: (query_cache_size - qcache_free_memory) / qcache_queries_in_cache

**There are lots of rows being sorted.**

While there is nothing wrong with a high amount of row sorting, you might want to make sure that the queries which require a lot of sorting use indexed columns in the ORDER BY clause, as this will result in much faster sorting

**There are too many joins without indexes.**

This means that joins are doing full table scans. Adding indexes for the columns being used in the join conditions will greatly speed up table joins

**The rate of reading the first index entry is high.**

This usually indicates frequent full index scans. Full index scans are faster than table scans but require lots of CPU cycles in big tables, if those tables that have or had high volumes of UPDATEs and DELETEs, running 'OPTIMIZE TABLE' might reduce the amount of and/or speed up full index scans. Other than that full index scans can only be reduced by rewriting queries.

**The rate of reading data from a fixed position is high.**

This indicates that many queries need to sort results and/or do a full table scan, including join queries that do not use indexes. Add indexes where applicable.

**The rate of reading the next table row is high.**

This indicates that many queries are doing full table scans. Add indexes where applicable.

**Many temporary tables are being written to disk instead of being kept in memory.**

Increasing max_heap_table_size and tmp_table_size might help. However some temporary tables are always being written to disk, independent of the value of these variables. To eliminate these you will have to rewrite your queries to avoid those conditions (Within a temporary table: Presence of a BLOB or TEXT column or presence of a column bigger than 512 bytes) as mentioned in the MySQL Documentation

**MyISAM key buffer (index cache) % used is low.**

You may need to decrease the size of key_buffer_size, re-examine your tables to see if indexes have been removed, or examine queries and expectations about what indexes are being used.

**The rate of opening tables is high.**

Opening tables requires disk I/O which is costly. Increasing table_open_cache might avoid this.

**The rate of opening files is high.**

Consider increasing open_files_limit, and check the error log when restarting after changing open_files_limit.

**Too many table locks were not granted immediately.**

Optimize queries and/or use InnoDB to reduce lock wait.

**Too many table locks were not granted immediately.**

Optimize queries and/or use InnoDB to reduce lock wait.

**Too many connections are aborted.**

Connections are usually aborted when they cannot be authorized. This article might help you track down the source.

**The InnoDB log file size is not an appropriate size, in relation to the InnoDB buffer pool.**

Especially on a system with a lot of writes to InnoDB tables you should set innodb_log_file_size to 25% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. However the bigger this value, the longer the recovery time will be when database crashes, so this value should not be set much higher than 256 MiB. Please note however that you cannot simply change the value of this variable. You need to shutdown the server, remove the InnoDB log files, set the new value in my.cnf, start the server, then check the error logs if everything went fine. See also this blog entry

EDIT

```
    -------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM 
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 461M (Tables: 168)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 16K (Tables: 1)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 8

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 25d 22h 33m 27s (1B q [533.080 qps], 35M conn, TX: 801B, RX: 148B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 71% / 29%
[--] Total buffers: 1020.0M global + 14.6M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 3.2G (41% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (7/1B)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 55% (84/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 300.0M/317.3M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (35B cached / 18K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 79.6% (743M cached / 933M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 34376
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (48K temp sorts / 68M sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (1K on disk / 17M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 76% (8M created / 35M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 98% (504 open / 511 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (678/41K)
[!!] Table locks acquired immediately: 74%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 512.0M/16.0K
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Optimize queries and/or use InnoDB to reduce lock wait
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (> 128M)
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade -- Support of 5.5 ended about 7 years ago.

Tip-top recommendation:  Switch your tables from MyISAM to InnoDB.  And be sure to adjust `key_buffer_size` down to 20M and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` higher, but not so high that it causes swapping.

Top recommendation:  Use the [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) that you have been capturing.  Digest it and let's discuss the 'worst' couple of queries.

Well, maybe there is nothing much in the slowlog ("Slow queries: 0% (1/763K)").  So lower `long_query_time` to `0.4`

The query cache *may* be hurting more than it is helping.  It is hard to say.

Not much of the 8MB is taken up by MySQL; do you have other apps running on the same machine?  Changing memory size will not relieve CPU issues.  Using a little more memory to raise `table_open_cache`, `open_files_limit`, etc, *may* help with the CPU.

If you are not using MyISAM, lower `key_buffer_size` to `20M`.

Ignore the note about "fragmented tables".

Turn off the `general_log`; it rapidly fills the disk.  (Not much CPU impact.)

"Up for: 22m 39s" -- The analysis is mostly focused on "startup" activity; hence does not adequately address your question.  Wait 24 hours.

Deeper analysis:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: Thanks. The database uses MyISAM. The table_open_cache and open_files_limit were lowered just prior to this post per automated recommendations. General_log was only activated prior to posting. This is a dedicated server that only runs this one app. We were able to dig up a few slow queries that may be contributing. We opened a new thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165126/how-to-optimize-slow-mysql-queries.

Comment: I added a new _first_ paragraph.

Comment: I recall there being some reason why we were not able to convert to InnoDB previously but can't recall the reasoning. Can you think of anything that may cause conflict?

Comment: @master00 - What version of MySQL?  Only recent versions of InnoDB could handle `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL`.  Theoretically, there is no compelling reason to stick with MyISAM.

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.50, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: Support for 5.5 ended several years ago.  `FULLTEXT` was first available in MySQL in 5.6.  (And 5.7 and 8.0.)

Comment: Pretty sure we're using FULLTEXT on 5.5.

Comment: Regarding the "focused on startup activity" part: this is especially true as a number of the recommendations were things like "the rate of opening tables is high" or "the rate of reading the first index is high", which are things that tend to happen more during and just after the server starts.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Clarification:  In 5.6, `FULLTEXT` was available only with Engine=MyISAM.  In 5.6 InnoDB implemented `FULLTEXT`, too.  With a "cold" cache, a lot of disk reads are needed. -- That is what I would expect shortly after restart.

Answer (score 1):

Before I get started, I'll mention that everything in the recommended list is worth looking at and I agree strongly with the other answer that 5.5 is crazy-old — to the point of not even getting security patches. Upgrading is a very good idea.

---

That out of the way, I want to focus on this:

> This database has run fine for years with no significant spikes in traffic or changes to the database

With that in mind, I know two common reasons you can see a sudden drop in performance like this:

1. The disks are on the verge of failing, such that some disk I/O operations are slow or repeating. If this is your issue, you'll likely find other evidence of it in the core server (not MySql) logs... *but not always!*
2. As you see data growth — not just over time but in terms of business growth (hopefully the business has more customers than it did when the server was installed) — it takes more memory to keep active records buffered in RAM instead of frequently reading from the (much slower) disks than it used to. You can hit a tipping point, where suddenly many of your queries that used to finish entirely in RAM now need to spill out to disk.

Yes, yes, I know both of these are disk issues, while the problem presents as CPU use. However, disk I/O problems often show up as CPU load issues, with processes waiting on disk to complete.

The solution to both of these usually involves hardware upgrades... but you can delay this if it's the second reason by working the list of recommendations in your question.

Comment: The CPU load average usually doesnt exceeds 50%. I/O numbers look good. But top says MYSQL is consistently using 600% of CPU. Can you please check slow queries we found here and see if you still think it may be related to disks? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165483/slow-queries-contributing-to-high-cpu-consumption?noredirect=1#comment125797236_71165483

Comment: @master00 that doesn't rule out #2, where RAM only runs low during the heavier use times, and so suddenly a mildly heavy period has drastic performance implications.

Comment: Will a disk health tool help to rule out #1? Or what would you recommend to rule that out?

Comment: The health tool might help, but only if SMART is enabled and in use on the disks (some high-throughput server builds turn it off for performance ...not the best idea imo... and some low-end server builds never turn it on or have it misconfigured). Otherwise it's digging through system logs looking for messages about bad sectors or similar. I'm fortunate enough to not have needed to do this very often, so I can't tell you what exactly to look for.

Comment: You've scared me with the HDD issue. It's running a RAID 0. This machine is also running an EOL CentOS so it need a complete overhaul anyway. Any idea which logs would contain evidence of drive failure?

Comment: No. I only manage a small handful of linux servers; we mostly have Windows here. But if you're running RAID 0, on a machine old enough to have MySql 5.5 and EOL OS, it's old enough the very next thing I'd do is make sure my backups are working.

Comment: @master00 - How many "cores"?  Does your app have multiple connections running at the same time?  Is the RAID 0 performed in the OS?  Or on a controller card?

Comment: 8 cores. Only one instance of MySQL if that's what you mean? I believe it's a software RAID but not certain if it's hardware as well as the hosting provider configured the RAID 0 (4x - 1TB drives). Indexing the database helped bring down the CPU usage but it's still around 300%. Tried to alter table to InnoDB but it caused a 500 error so I had to revert. Memory consumption remains high 143112k free of 8GB.

Answer (score 1):

Master00, since you need and want to stay with MyISAM, consider the following suggestions to IMPROVE your response time with MyISAM.

Corrected variable name to key_cache_age_threshold - my humble apologies. Wilson

```
key_cache_block_size=16384  # from 1024 to reduce overhead managing key_buffer data
key_cache_division_limit=50  # from 100 percent to enable Hot / Warm cache separation
key_cache_age_threshold=7200  # from 300 seconds before AGE_OUT causes another READ
```

and the these three changes will reduce your key_reads Rate Per Second significantly.

For additional useful tips, view my profile for contact info and get in touch.

Comment: Are those parameters compatible with 5.5? It caused MySQL to fail on restart. [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'key_cache_threshold=7200'

Comment: You may use   SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE  'key_cache%;' to verify available variables in your version.  Apparently key_cache_threshold variable is not available in your version.  Attempt to apply suggestions one at a time, please.  The other two will help, if you can use them.

Comment: I can't find any reference of key_cache_threshold being a valid variable for any version. Please provide documentation.

Comment: @master00  My humble apologies.  Variable name corrected to be key_cache_age_threshold.  Now you should have reduced key_reads Rate Per Second and improved performance.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go.

Comment: @master00 One more suggestion for your configuration,  key_buffer_size=300M;  from 128M  to support ALL of your 273M of MyISAM indexes in RAM.  Every little bit in RAM helps.

Comment: @master00 Any comment after application of the suggestions and 3 days of production?  Positive or negative?

Comment: @master00  Have you had time to implement suggestions to improve MyISAM performance?  Any comment you could leave?  Positive or negative.  Thanks

Comment: We have added the configurations but based strictly on the data we have been monitoring we havne't seen any notable changes. Not to say that there isn't  improvement we just don't have any data to account for any changes positive or negative.

Comment: @master00  Is this observation still true today?  ....  "but recently Mysql CPU consumption has spiked to a consistent 600%" -  from the first page of your question.

Comment: CPU consumption is down by approx. 50% which appears to be attributed to optimizing some slow queries. The changes you suggested do not appear to have yielded any measurable results based on the limited data we have been monitoring. Memory, CPU, and I/O remain consistent before and after implementation.

Comment: @master00  Could you post current complete report from MySQLTuner for comparison to oriiginal posted?  I think we will find some improvements in MyISAM statistics.  Thank you.  You may need to post the report to pastebin.com and share the link because this question is close to the space limit for one question.

Comment: Updated mysqltuner results are posted above. Everything seems pretty consistent as far as I can tell. Any idea for resolving the cache prunes and table locks?

Comment: @master00  Your 'Query cache prunes per day: :34376 could be eliminated with configuration changes of query_cache_size=0 and query_cache_type=0  (for OFF).  You may even find with these two changes, your CPU is less busy and queries complete faster.  Get in touch for further assistance, please.